# the reason for solving the homogeneous ODE part in non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am study differential equations and there is something that I dont understand about the way

for, let's say $$a(x)y''+b(x)y'+c(x)y=g\left(x\right)$$

we are finding $y_h:a(x)y''+b(x)y'+c(x)y=0$ first, and then adding $y_p$ to it. so the equation can be looked at like this:

$$a(x)\left[y_h+y_p\right]''+b(x)\left[y_h+y_p\right]'+c(x)\left[y_h+y_p\right]=g(x)\\a(x)y_h''+a(x)y_p''+b(x)y_h'+b(x)y_p'+c(x)y_h+c(x)y_p=g(x)\\\underbrace{a(x)y''_h+b(x)y'_h+c(x)y_h}_{\LARGE0}+a(x)y''_p+b(x)y'_p+c(x)y_p=g(x)\\a(x)y''_p+b(x)y'_p+c(x)y_p=g(x)$$
now this is pretty obvious, because we solved $y_p$ like this.

what I cant understand is why searching for $y_h$ at all? why is this a part of the solution?

Comment: Suppose $y_p(x)$ is ANY particular solution, without regard to initial or boundary conditions.  Then, we can add a homogeneous solution to $y_p(x)$ such that $y=y_h+y_p$ satisfies the initial or boundary conditions.  Since we have a second order ODE, there will be two linearly independent homogenous solutions, each carrying an as of yet undetermined coefficient.

Comment: @MarkViola so it is just like the constant in integral?

Comment: Yes, they are integration constants.

Comment: @MarkViola please write it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we find the homogeneous solution of inhomogeneous Differential Equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264847/why-do-we-find-the-homogeneous-solution-of-inhomogeneous-differential-equations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $y_p$ is *any* particular solution to the second order ODE.  Since there are also two linearly independent homogeneous solutions $y_{h_1}$ and $y_{h_2}$ to the same ODE, we can write the general solution as

$$y=y_p+C_1y_{h_1}+C_2y_{h_2}$$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two integration constants.

Finally, the integration constants are found by enforcing two conditions, either initial, boundary, or mixed conditions.